# remove quote from list<string> using linq

Tags: c#

I have a List strings and each value has a leading quote that needs to be removed. Now there could be quotes further down the string and those will need to stay.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("'Value1");
strings.Add("'Values2 This 2nd ' should stay");
```

Is there a linq way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strings.ForEach(s => s = s.TrimStart('\''));
```

---

EDIT by Olivier Jacot-Descombes (it demonstrates that this solution does not work):

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("'Value1");
strings.Add("'Values2 This 2nd ' should stay");

Console.WriteLine("Before:");
foreach (string s in strings) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

strings.ForEach(s => s = s.TrimStart('\''));

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("After:");
foreach (string s in strings) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

This produces the following output on the console:

```
Before:
'Value1
'Values2 This 2nd ' should stay

After:
'Value1
'Values2 This 2nd ' should stay
```

Comment: Because strings are immutable, that won't change the contents of the list; it will just calculate new strings and immediately make them eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Yes phoog, he would have to do something like: `Enumerable.Range(0, strings.Count - 1).ForEach(i => strings[i] = strings[i].TrimStart('\''));`. However, doing it with the good old for-loop seems easier.

Comment: In any of the solutions submitted new strings would be created. I chose to use ForEach because you could either save the results to your current variable or create an extension method. I not sure why this deserves a vote down.

Comment: @Brownman98: I down voted it, because it does not work. The List will still point to the old strings after the ForEach. Your ForEach creates a new string, but it will never be replaced in the list. I added a test to your solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
strings = strings.Select(x => x.StartsWith("'") ? x.Substring(1) : x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
strings.Select(s => s.StartsWith("'") ? s.Substring(1) : s);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = strings.Select(s => s.TrimStart('\''));
```

Note: This will remove all leading occurrences of ('). However, I assume that you will not have a string like `"''Value1"`.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is really unnecessary for this. You could just use TrimStart() by itself:

```
strings.Add("'Value1".TrimStart('\''));
```